# Is it possible to run classic asp and webpages (webmatrix c#) on the same site?

Tags: c#, razor, asp-classic, webmatrix

I have a very old homepage made from classic asp that works like a charm, but we need to upload images easy and save them on the server.

Previously we did this with a asp.net webforms page on the same server, which worked like a charm. But it's getting really unreliable and need to be exchanged for something else.

My idea then have been to build a webpage with matrix, razor and c#. So tonight I've been fiddeling and made it work on my computer and local webserver.

My problem now is that I need this to run on the same site as the classic asp and I don't really know how to configure this and make it work.

I have an App_Data and bin folder, do these go in the rootfolder of the site or can I put them anywhere and the page will look for any App_Data and bin folders and running the code?

I have done som testing but since I don't have a testserver to try on and can only try it on the real server I don't want to try to much with the possibility of me crasching the site.

Any help is appreciated :-)

Comment: If you're asking if classic asp and asp.net pages can run on the same site then the answer is yes. Obviously Classic needs to be enabled in IIS as it's disabled by default.  App_data and bin go in the root folder. What may cause the most difficulty is getting your production IIS server (as opposed to the dev server which comes with WebMatrix) to serve  standalone razor pages directly - they're generally used as templates within asp.net MVC

Comment: Yes, i found I got some problems there and I've decided to try with webforms pages instead, looks like it's a little less hassle, especially since I don't have access to the server but have to talk to support to get them to configure it for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the two environments on the same site, but, you cannot, at least not easily, share session state between them. It’s not something that I would recommend doing.

That said, so long as you don’t need to share the session state between your existing homepage, and the upload page, i.e. the upload page can act as a stand-alone system, then you should be OK.

Comment: Thanks, it worked after a little bit of tweaking and help with setting to a higher App-pool on the IIS, from 2.0 - 4.0.